# Subtle Quicksort Stability Issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to create a quicksort implementation for a school project that sorts a CSV file and am having a very hard time with it. According to the project specification, sorting each column of a CSV file in order will force an unstable sort to become stable, that is: "./sort --algorithm quicksort -k 1,2,3,4,5 input.csv" should produce the same results as "./sort --algorithm insertion -k 1,2,3,4,5 input.csv"

In order to preserve previous sorts the sorts are performed in reverse, like this:

```
for (int current_key = config.sort_columns.size()-1; current_key >= 0; current_key--){
    sorting_algorithm(records, config, config.sort_columns[current_key]-1);
}
```

Where config.sort_columns is vector of all of the sort columns specified by the -k argument.

Here is my input:

```
name,breed,date of birth,date of death,avg eggs per week 
Marilyn,Isa Red,2011-04-24,N/A,6 
Brian,Derp,2010-01-15,2011-12-01,4 
Chrissy,Ent,2012-02-08,N/A,3 
Mildred,Araucana,2011-05-01,N/A,3 
Jimmy,Ent,2006-02-30,N/A,15 
Mabel,Isa Red,2011-04-26,N/A,5 
Myrtle,Araucana,2011-08-01,N/A,0 
Myrtle,Araucana,2011-05-01,2011-07-13,0 
Adam,Ent,2010-01-01,N/A,10 
Isabel,Ent,2009-04-01,N/A,2 
Jimmy,Ent,2006-02-30,2011-03-24,1 
Jimmy,Derp,2003-02-30,2010-03-24,8 
Myrtle,Herp,2011-08-01,N/A,0
```

Here is the output of my insertion sort (should be and appears to be correct):

```
name,breed,date of birth,date of death,avg eggs per week 
Adam,Ent,2010-01-01,N/A,10 
Brian,Derp,2010-01-15,2011-12-01,4 
Chrissy,Ent,2012-02-08,N/A,3 
Isabel,Ent,2009-04-01,N/A,2 
Jimmy,Derp,2003-02-30,2010-03-24,8 
Jimmy,Ent,2006-02-30,2011-03-24,1 
Jimmy,Ent,2006-02-30,N/A,15 
Mabel,Isa Red,2011-04-26,N/A,5 
Marilyn,Isa Red,2011-04-24,N/A,6 
Mildred,Araucana,2011-05-01,N/A,3 
Myrtle,Araucana,2011-05-01,2011-07-13,0 
Myrtle,Araucana,2011-08-01,N/A,0 
Myrtle,Herp,2011-08-01,N/A,0
```

And here is the output of my quicksort:

```
name,breed,date of birth,date of death,avg eggs per week
Adam,Ent,2010-01-01,N/A,10
Brian,Derp,2010-01-15,2011-12-01,4
Chrissy,Ent,2012-02-08,N/A,3
Isabel,Ent,2009-04-01,N/A,2
Jimmy,Ent,2006-02-30,2011-03-24,1
Jimmy,Ent,2006-02-30,N/A,15
Jimmy,Derp,2003-02-30,2010-03-24,8
Mabel,Isa Red,2011-04-26,N/A,5
Marilyn,Isa Red,2011-04-24,N/A,6
Mildred,Araucana,2011-05-01,N/A,3
Myrtle,Herp,2011-08-01,N/A,0
Myrtle,Araucana,2011-08-01,N/A,0
Myrtle,Araucana,2011-05-01,2011-07-13,0
```

As you can see, this is almost correct except that the second column is wrong when the first column matches (e.g. "Derp" should come before both "Ents").

And finally, here is my quicksort implementation:

```
int sort_quick_partition(std::vector<Record> &records, bool (*comparison)(string, string), int sort_key, int left, int right){
    /*
    Partition the vector and return the address of the new pivot.

    @param less - Vector of elements less than pivot.
    @param greater - Vector of elements greater than pivot.
    */

    // Setup 
    int store_location;
    Record pivot = records[right];
    Record temp_record;

    // Loop through and partition the vector within the provided bounds
    store_location = left - 1;
    for (int j = left; j < right; j++){
        if (comparison(records[j].fields[sort_key],pivot.fields[sort_key])){
            store_location += 1;
            std::swap(records[store_location], records[j]);
        }
    }

    std::swap(records[store_location+1], records[right]);

    return store_location+1;
}

void sort_quick_helper(std::vector<Record> &records, bool (*comparison)(string, string), int sort_key, int left, int right){
    /*
    Actually performs the quick sort.

    @param sub_list - Vector to sort.
    @param *comparison - Comparison to perform.
    @param sort_key - Which column to sort by.
    @param left - Left side of active sort zone.
    @param right - Right side of active sort zone.
    */

    // Setup
    int new_pivot;

    // Make sure the list has 2 or more items
    if (left < right){
        // Partition the vector and get the new pivot value
        new_pivot = sort_quick_partition(records, comparison, sort_key, left, right);

        // Sort elements less than the pivot
        sort_quick_helper(records, comparison, sort_key, left, new_pivot-1);

        // Sort elements greater than the pivot
        sort_quick_helper(records, comparison, sort_key, new_pivot+1, right);
    }
}

void sort_quick(std::vector<Record> &records, Configuration &config, int sort_key){
    /*
    Perform a quick sort on the records.

    @param &records - Vector of Record structures representing the file.
    @param &config - Reference to a global configuration structure.
    @param sort_key - Which column to sort by.
    */

    // Decide if it needs to be reversed
    bool (*comparison)(string, string);
    if (config.reverse){
        comparison = &comparison_gte;
    } else {
        comparison = &comparison_lte;
    }

    // Call the sort
    sort_quick_helper(records, comparison, sort_key, 0, records.size()-1);
}
```

Note that "sorting_algorithm" is a function pointer that points to the active sort, "sort_quick" in this case.

Does anyone see what could possible be wrong? I've been trying to fix this for days and I'm pulling my hair out at this point. Thanks everyone!

Comment: in your example, what is `-k`? if it's 1,2,3,4,5 this is not stability issue, because it's a wrong order regardless of stability.

Comment: Stable quicksort implementations are difficult to write without using extra memory during the partitioning step.  I would suggest looking into stable partitioning algorithms as a starting point.

Comment: Yes -k is 1,2,3,4,5 by default. Yeah I kinda suspected that but I don't really have any idea how to fix it. I copied my sorting implementation almost verbatim from the lecture slides and it can't seem to sort correctly. This led me to think maybe the rest of my program is wrong (the part that gathers the input, decides what algorithm to use, etc.) but then I realized that can't be it because it works as intended with the other sorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that you can make a stable sort out of an unstable one by sorting repeatedly. Consider the final sort: it isn't guaranteed to preserve the previous orderings when it sees equal keys (that's what unstable means).

Instead, what you need to do is sort on a key which unambiguously orders the input - so you need to do one sort, where the key you sort on is all the columns rather than an individual column.

So when you compare the records "Myrtle,Araucana,2011-08-01,N/A,0" and "Myrtle,Araucana,2011-05-01,2011-07-13,0" you need to compare fields in order until you find a pair that are not equal. (This is known as lexicographic ordering.) You may even need to incorporate the original position, if you need to preserve the order of completely equal records.

Of course if this wasn't homework you'd probably be looking at `std::stable_sort`. (A sequence of stable sorts on the columns in reverse order would be fine.)

Comment: Here's what the project guide says:
"It is possible to force an unstable sort to be stable by specifying every column, in order, using the “-k” option to specify every column in the file.  For example, the output of “./csort --algorithm quicksort -k 1,2,3,4,5 chickens.csv” will be the same as the output of “./csort -a insertion -k 1,2,3,4,5 chickens.csv”" It says were supposed to use ASCII string comparisons for every field.

Comment: Yes - the question is: does -k mean sort repeatedly on different keys, or sort once with a compound key? Only the latter works.

Comment: Hum, could you elaborate on what a compound key is please? I read around online and what I thought I had to do was sort the columns in reverse order, that is "-k 1,2,3,4,5" means to sort the whole list by columns 5-1. The technique I'm using now works on stable sorts (not really sure if that means anything or if it's just a coincidence)

Comment: In this case compound key means treating all the columns in order as a single key, as I tried to explain in my answer above. Smith, Alan comes before Smith, John in the phone book - the last names are equal so you order by first name.

Comment: Hum, so in my Record struct vector I would need some variable to keep track if a given column should be included in the sort based on if it's been sorted before?

Comment: Oh, and does the reverse sort thing I was talking about only work on stable sorts or something?

Comment: This ended up being the correct solution. I needed to compare each field, as Alan said. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your sorting looks stable as you have chosen the pivot to be the `right`most element. However, in the end the line.

```
std::swap(records[store_location+1], records[right]);
```

is swapping the two records just like that, even when they would be equal. Add a check to sort only when they are not equal:

```
// You'll probably use your comparison() function here.
if ( records[store_location+1].fields[sort_key] != records[right].fields[sort_key] ) {
    std::swap(records[store_location+1], records[right]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and there was no change, thanks for your response though.